# jquery post check json response

Tags: php, jquery, json

Have a script which is adding products to a cart session and the php is returning the response back to the jquery post function. Problem is that I can't check the returned response to run through some animation.

My jquery code is:

```
var product = {
            action: 'shs_add_to_cart',
            'nonce': wp_nonce_value,
            'product': product_id,
            'title': product_title,
            'qty': quantity.val()
        };

        $.post(
          shsAjaxURL.ajaxurl, product,
          function(status) {
            var response = $.parseJSON(status);

            console.log('response');

            if(response == 'success') {
              message.find('p').text('Item added to cart');
              message.fadeIn(300);
              message.delay(2500).fadeOut(300);
            }
            else {
              message.find('p').text('Could not add to cart');
              message.fadeIn(300);
              message.delay(2500).fadeOut(300);
            }

        });
```

The PHP code works fine as it adds the value to the session cart

```
 $_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(
                array(
                    'item_id'   => $product,
                    'item_name' => $title,
                    'item_qty'  => $qty
                )
        );

        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode('success');
        wp_die();
```

I get the following response

```
"success"
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: use  print_r( json_encode(array('success')) );    or wp_die(json_encode(array('success')));

Comment: `console.log('response');` -> `console.log(response);`

Comment: That formatted the return back however any console.log inside the function (status) does not return.

Comment: Which browser you are using Note: Some old browsers like IE8 won't support console.log() feature.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ajax with dataType json, like this:

```
$.ajax({
      url:shsAjaxURL.ajaxurl,
      data: product,  
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      success:function(data) {
         console.log(data.success);
      }
   });
```

And then in your php code:

```
$_SESSION['cart_items'] = array(
                array(
                    'item_id'   => $product,
                    'item_name' => $title,
                    'item_qty'  => $qty
                )
        );
        $data['success'] = "success";
        echo json_encode($data);
```